# Adding item to every dictionary in a list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list where there are nested dictionaries, such as the following structure:

```json
[
{'family': '',
  'given': '',
  'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},

 {'family': '',
  'given': '',
  'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},

 {'family': '',
  'given name': '',
  'localId': '',
  'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},

 {'family': '',
  'given name': '',
  'affiliation': [{'': ''}]}
]
```

I want to add an **id** dictionary to each of the nested dictionary in this such that the structure becomes:

```json
[
 {'id':'',
  'family': '',
  'given': '',
  'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},

 {'id':'',
  'family': '',
  'given': '',
  'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},

 {'id':'',
  'family': '',
  'given name': '',
  'localId': '',
  'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},

 {'id':'',
  'family': '',
  'given name': '',
  'affiliation': [{'': ''}]}
]
```

I tried the following code, where **tmp** is my list name:

```
tmp.append({'id':df.id[0]})
```

which results in:

```
[
{'family': '',
  'given': '',
  'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},

 {'family': '',
  'given': '',
  'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},

 {'family': '',
  'given name': '',
  'localId': '',
  'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},

 {'family': '',
  'given name': '',
  'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},
 {'id': '776'}
]
```

Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem so that i am able to add **id** in each dictionary?

I would prefer a one line code instead of loop so that i can apply to each cell of a dataframe where I have these nested dictionaries.

Comment: `for d in temp: d['id'] = '776'`

Comment: Creating a `class` for this would seem to be a better solution?

Comment: `for i, d in enumerate(temp): d['id'] = df.id[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[i.update({'id':''}) for i in tmp]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop the list items and add the new field

```
l = [
  {'family': '',
    'given': '',
    'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},

  {'family': '',
    'given': '',
    'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},

  {'family': '',
    'given name': '',
    'localId': '',
    'affiliation': [{'': ''}]},

  {'family': '',
    'given name': '',
    'affiliation': [{'': ''}]}
]
for e in l:
  e['id'] = ''
```

Comment: i want to avoid looping due to reason specified in the question. The solution by @rdas works perfect in this case.

Comment: @Hanif read the code ... `for d in temp: d['id'] = '776'` there is a loop there - isnt it?

Comment: yes there is. but i can as I said, a one line solution would be better so i can use it as a lambda function to apply on each cell of my dataframe. That's why i choose this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to loop through your list of dictionaries and add 'id' attribute each one of them

```
for i in range(len(tmp)):
    tmp[i]['id'] = ''
```